# Add padding arround input

Tags: css

I'm working on this code. I would like to add some space around this input field:

```
 <span class="theSpan">
      <h:inputText id="search" class="input_style" value="#{accounts.searchString}"></h:inputText>
      <h:commandButton value="Search by title" action="#{bookBean.searchByTitle(accounts.searchString)}">
      <f:ajax execute="search" render="output"></f:ajax>
      </h:commandButton>
 </span>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .input_style {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    /*    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, serif;*/
    /*    font-size: 16px;*/
    /*background-position: 270px -10px;*/
    /*    background-image: url('http://www.kirupa.com/images/search.png');*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.theSpan { 
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

**Visual result:**

[image]

How can I add some space between the input filed and the table? Also how can I place the text "Search by title" at line line with input field?

Comment: `padding` and `margin` are 2 completely different things. `padding` is the space inside your element while `margin` is the space outside your element.

Comment: Can you post rendered HTML rather than ASP or whatever it is please?

Comment: Here you are http://pastebin.com/2gAadfKG

Comment: Are you sure about that? it doesn't match your code above the id, class etc.

Comment: I removed the css code. Here it is http://pastebin.com/SsqGFz1T

Comment: "Search by title" is actually a button, why does it look like plain text in the screenshot above?

Comment: Because I have global CSS file from web site template.

Comment: Adding a simple padding might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put space between two elements use `margin` (which adds space outside of the borders of your element), not `padding` (which adds space inside the border of your element).

To vertically align the text next to the input, place it inside of a `span` element and apply the following CSS to that `span`.

Since a text field and a span are both inline elements, they should semantically both be placed into a container (block level) element. That is the element that should get the margin applied to it.

```css
.input_style {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.theButton { 
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

div { margin-bottom: 30px;
      border:1px solid red; /* only here to show the layout */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search" class="input_style" >
  <button class="theButton">Search By Title</button>
</div>
<div>
  This is the next item in the flow of the document.
</div>
```

> Another way to solve this issue is to simply make the button the same
>   height as the input field, then alignment isn't necessary since both elements are the same height:

```css
/* Note that this rule now applies to the input field and the button */
.input_style, .theButton {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Now we just reset aspects of the button that are different
   from the input field  */
.theButton { 
    width:auto;
    border:0;
}

div { margin-bottom: 30px;
      border:1px solid red; /* only here to show the layout */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search" class="input_style" >
  <button class="theButton">Search By Title</button>
</div>
<div>
  This is the next item in the flow of the document.
</div>
```

Comment: First problem is solved. But I tried your proposal and it's not working. I updated the code.

Comment: @PeterPenzov You didn't put the `span` in the right place. Just put it around the text that needs to be vertically aligned.

Comment: Very good but how I Can vertically align "Search By Title" with search filed?

Comment: How would you like it aligned? Right now, my code has it vertically aligned so that the "Search by Title" is bottom aligned with the search field. You can change `bottom` to a variety of other values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Place "Search By Title" at the center

Comment: No problem, I've updated the code to use `vertical-align:middle` instead of `vertical-align:bottom`.

Comment: Hmm. It looks little down. Maybe there is some padding?

Comment: Looks dead in the middle to me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ScottMarcus See the comments right below the question, "Search by title" is actually a button. I'm very confused too.

Comment: I found the problem. I have global CSS file with content vertical-align: top;. And this moves the button "Search by title" at wrong position. How I can ignore the global CSS file for this component?

Comment: I've updated my answer and changed the alignment to `baseline`. I didn't realize that the adjacent content was a button. Take a look now. This should override the global CSS instruction.

Comment: @Pangloss Yes, you are right. I just became aware of that and changed the alignment to account for it. Thanks.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The vertical-align should be set to middle I guess. As far as I see in the demo, you don't need to do any https://jsfiddle.net/nffp7qce/

Comment: @PeterPenzov I have added a second solution, which solves the issue by just making the button the same height as the input field. Take a look.

Answer (score 5):

Add margin after the input-style

```
.input_style{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

> padding creates space inside the element and margin creates outside the element so you need to use margin.

Coming to "Search by title" use `line-height` css in this and line-height should be equal to height of input

Comment: Hi Gaurav, please stop editing the CSS tag out of questions that involve CSS. Further, make sure your suggested edits fix **all** problems with the post, including grammar and spelling, as well as fluff removal. Thanks!

Comment: i tagged out which has no need to css coding in answer...check the question thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your entire block in a div tag. That way you can easily control both the spage around the form and the line height alignment.
Add CSS

```
.my-form-wraper {
    /*set margins, padding, line-height, etc. here ^/
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class='my-form-wraper'>
<h:inputText id="search" class="input_style" value="#{accounts.searchString}"></h:inputText>
<h:commandButton value="Search by title" action="#{bookBean.searchByTitle(accounts.searchString)}">
<f:ajax execute="search" render="output"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
</div>
```